# Eclipse syntax coloring settings gone.

Tags: eclipse

I use customized syntax coloring for my Eclipse editor and it has reverted back to the default settings. This is the second time in a couple weeks that it has happened. Any ideas as to why this is happening or how I can get my custom settings back? I have a very specific coloring scheme that I like to use and it takes forever to manually set!

Comment: you haven't switched your workspace, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you switching across workspaces? As I understand eclipse preferences are stored in `.settings/` present in workspace's root directory.

I export eclipse preferences and import it when I switch workspaces. Another cool trick  I found is to close projects when I do not use them.

Eclipse official link on how to export preferences:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftimpandexp.htm

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes simply `import/export` would not be enough, so you may need a list of `.pref` files where the syntax coloring settings are stored. What I have here is not complete and I just list what I use and I hope it helps.

(I process `.java`, `.jsp`, `.xml`, `js` and `.properties` files.)

You can find them by searching `.pref` files in your workspace. Remember to adjust your searching options to look into subfolders.

```
org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.html.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.ant.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.sqleditor.prefs
org.eclipse.debug.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.mxml.core.prefs
org.python.pydev.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.as.core.prefs
com.adobe.flexide.css.core.prefs
org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui.prefs
org.epic.perleditor.prefs
org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prefs
```

You may copy them when you finish adjusting your syntax coloring settings. When needed, search `.pref` again to get access to their locations, and restore your settings by copying the lines with color code, in order to avoid unpredictable side effect. As I can see this is the only way, inconvenient buy effective.